# Difficulty fitting polynomial model to data

Tags: r, polynomial

I need to fit a model to an existing dataset such that I can use the parameters to replicate the best-fit curve to manage the behaviour of an application.  I've been trying to fit a polynomial model, but cannot escape the problem of (I think) edge effects (?) - despite fitting the model to a broader-ranged dataset than my operational requirements (exemplified by `newdat`).

The following R script illustrates:

```
dat = read.csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/geotheory/10ad6b2051e69213f81ccf2366938cda/raw/485c98381579d74ec581e34c1ebfa80b66b76d69/poly-test.csv')

# polynomial model
pm = lm(vy ~ poly(vx, degree=20, raw=TRUE), data = dat)

newdat = data.frame(vx = 10^seq(4,6,.02))
newdat$vy = predict(pm, newdata = newdat)
#> Warning in predict.lm(pm, newdata = newdat): prediction from a rank-
#> deficient fit may be misleading

plot(dat, log='x', pch=16, cex=.6)
lines(newdat, col='red', lwd=3)
```

[image]

I've experimented with different degrees but nothing works.

If another model is better suited I'd be happy to take advice.  Grateful for suggestions.

Comment: These points simply don't exhibit polynomial behavior (not even on this log-linear plot); using degree 20 (!) is going to cause all kinds of overfitting problems, as you can see.  What does `vy` represent, how is it measured, and how do you *expect* it to vary with `vx`?

Comment: Hmm. I've used this approach for similar problems in the past. Perhaps I need to fit to fewer data points.  Explaining `vx`/`vy` is going to be too painful - save to say I'm experimenting to resolve an problem to do with subsetting datasets that are typoically log-ish but not quite log-ish enough for a simple log model.

Comment: It occurs to me this question has paved the way to an unforgivably bad [stats joke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p16kx.png).

Comment: There are many seemingly simple functions that cannot be will approximated by polynomials. Try restricted cubic splines instead.

Comment: @rep_ho @Glen_b Yes it probably does belong better out of sight by default. Think `log polynomial`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fitting a linear vx but plotting it on a log scale.  Try taking the log in your lm model fit and then plot.

```
 pm = lm(vy ~ poly(I(log(vx)), degree=5, raw=TRUE), data = dat)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thanks Dave. What is the role of `I()` here? The model seems to work fine without it.

Comment: Glad it work out for your. The `I()` function is the AsIs function.  From help, "it is used to inhibit the interpretation of operators such as "+", "-", "*" and "^" as formula operators..." .  I thought I needed it to properly handle the log function, but was mistaken.